# Alternative substrate for nanomolding synthetic "gecko tape"

Tags: materials

I have been interested in the prospect of leveraging [Van der Waals force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_force) in an adhesive material for several years now.  The most notable example I have seen thus far is the highly publicized [GeckSkin](https://geckskin.umass.edu/) product resulting from biomimicry of Gecko locomotion.

Some key features of Nano-hair structure include:

> - anisotropic attachment
> - high pulloff to preload ratio
> - low detachment force
> - material independence / van der Waals adhesion
> - self-cleaning
> - anti-self matting
> - non-sticky default state.

There is obvious far reaching impacts of such materials in everything from robotics to home decor and without a supply (I have already contacted the team involved with little feedback on estimated time to market) I have been investigating the prospect of good old fashioned DIY.

In my pursuit I have come across a simple method of [NanoMolding synthetic gecko tape](http://www.nisenet.org/catalog/programs/biomimicry_synthetic_gecko_tape_through_nanomolding).  The key ingredient of which is the [Millipore Isopore Polycarbonate Filter Membrane (Product# TMTP04700)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00C10VPCY) which conveniently enough is sold on Amazon.

More information with respect to robotics can be found [here](https://robotics.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ronf/Gecko/).

Theoretically one could use the membrane to create a negative mold from which a more permanent reusable mold (possibly a Resin?) could then be used for future casts.  I figure resolution may be somewhat of an issue in this case, however, so this leads me to my question.

***TL;DR***
I would like to know if there are other materials with similar surface properties that may be good candidates to replace the membrane.  Something more readily available, reusable, lower cost, natural or man made.

***Bonus***  I am also open to suggestion on alternative methods for creating the [synthetic setae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_setae).

---

<sub>I had a hard time finding a place for this question as it is applicable to so many fields and there currently is not a dedicated ***[Material Science](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265751/stack-exchange-site-for-material-science)*** StackExchange community.</sub>

Comment: @downvoter do you have any constructive criticism as to why the down vote?  Do you know of a more appropriate forum for such a question?  I feel I have provided ample context and a well constructed, legitimate question with a clear goal in mind.  I ask the question as there may be common materials used in other fields I am unaware of that could be good candidates for the desired results.  The membrane, for example, is normally used for examination of airborne contaminants.

Comment: Just for the record on future bread crumbs:  The intention of my downvote comment is to insight a useful discussion as to where I may have a problem with this question as to help guide myself and others to a better solution.  Not to literally seek a response for the downvoter.

Comment: In 2008-2009 I've spend a significant amount of time trying to create microstructures with anodized alumina and various types of silicone rubber.  The main issue I ran into was that the setae would not demold properly, stick to each other , and get dirty after a few uses.  Producing large volumes was also an issue.  The interesting thing is that one does not actually need nanoscale structures for many applications.  MEMS scale or larger structures also work.

Comment: Great question but I think the development of synthetic setae is so cutting edge technology and highly specialized that I doubt you will get a good answer here.

Comment: This is just the sort of discussion I was after :).  Thanks guys for the responses thus far.  Most things sound good on paper until you actually try it out in the field.  I don't doubt this sort of thing has many challenges to overcome.  I'm still tempted to try it out.

Comment: The only idea I could give you that might help you with the demolding problem is to coat the micromachined or nanofabricated mold with parylene. Parylene deposition is a non line-of-sight process that deposits, molecule by molecule, a super fine layer of polyparaxylene , you can Google this process and see all the great material properties these coatings have.